# Build error while compiling ffmpeg on cygwin with libx264

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

configured ffmpeg(0.6.1) with below command (with x264-snapshot-20101228-2245 snapshot)
with Gcc version : gcc (GCC) 4.3.4 20090804 (release)

```
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-libx264 
--enable-gpl --disable-doc --enable-memalign-hack 
--extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

and after that, "make" command is giving below error.

```
CC      libavdevice/alldevices.o
CC      libavdevice/avdevice.o
CC      libavdevice/oss_audio.o
CC      libavdevice/vfwcap.o
CC      libavformat/4xm.o
In file included from /usr/include/endian.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/cygwin/types.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/sys/types.h:440,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:46,
                 from ./libavutil/common.h:34,
                 from ./libavutil/intreadwrite.h:25,
                 from libavformat/4xm.c:30:
/usr/include/byteswap.h:19: error: redefinition of `bswap_16'
./libavutil/x86/bswap.h:33: error: previous definition of `bswap_16' was here
/usr/include/byteswap.h:25: error: redefinition of `bswap_32'
./libavutil/x86/bswap.h:40: error: previous definition of `bswap_32' was here
/usr/include/byteswap.h:31: error: redefinition of `bswap_64'
./libavutil/bswap.h:70: error: previous definition of `bswap_64' was here
make: *** [libavformat/4xm.o] Error 1
bash: sudo: command not found
```

I checked lot of links showing same error but no solution has been provided. Anybody has any clue who already build ffmpeg on cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [fixed](http://git.ffmpeg.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=8fc0162ac44f3e60798552ca6d19387be95cae4c) in FFmpeg GIT by using `av_` prefix for `bswap` macros. You should update to the latest git `HEAD`.

Comment: Thanks Ismail, This error is gone with latest release of ffmpeg.